# equivalent of SIZE for data structure

Tags: fortran

I have a data structure like :

```
AllPaths%list_Pw(A,B)%vectors(C)%elements(D, E)
```

But for each pair of values `A,B` the length of `c` is different. And the length of `D,E` is different for each value of `C`.

The `SIZE` function work only for array but is there an equivalent for data structure, like:

```
Cmax=SIZElike(AllPaths%list_Pw(A,B)%vectors)
```

The alternative would be keeping the size of each `vectors` for each pair of `A,B` when I build my data structure, but I would be one more big array, with lot of information that I will not need...

***EDIT***

For example my `Amax=5` and `Bmax=5`

I would like to be able to know what is `Cmax` for `A=4` and `B=3`

```
AllPaths%list_Pw(4,3)%vectors(Cmax)
```

Because this `Cmax` would be different if `A=2` and `B=4` :

```
AllPaths%list_Pw(2,4)%vectors(Cmax)
```

***EDIT2***

How types are declared :

```
MODULE NewType
TYPE :: vector
    INTEGER, DIMENSION(:, :), ALLOCATABLE :: elements
END TYPE vector

TYPE :: ragged_array
    TYPE(vector), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: vectors
END TYPE ragged_array

TYPE :: List_RA
   TYPE(ragged_array),DIMENSION(:, :),ALLOCATABLE::List_PW
END TYPE List_RA
END MODULE
```

Comment: Are you saying that `c`, `d` and `e` are vectors (they shouldn't be), or that the bounds of the components vary?

Comment: I tried to edit my post to make it easier to understand. I have created subroutine to append `vectors` and `elements` for each couple of `A,B`, then I want to know the length of `vectors` for a specific couple of `A,B`

Comment: If `AllPaths%list_Pw(4,3)%vectors` is an array component then `size` and `ubound` will behave as expected.  Does it not?  (If it doesn't then it may be helpful for you to show how the types are declared.)

Comment: No...It give me an error if I want to use `size` saying that size work for `array`... I have edit my post with how types are made, once again : Thanks a lot !

Comment: What do you want to do with size once you figure out what it is?

Comment: @Craig : Update the size of an other structure and also read all `vectors` in a `DO` loop

Comment: Point being, the fact that the members are `ALLOCATABLE` means that the total amount of space consumed by the structure is not necessarily all in one place, thus I'm not sure the value is actually useful to you.  As far as reading all `vectors`, I don't see how a size is useful for that purpose; you're going to need to loop anyway, so you can get the specific size information that you need at the point where you need it.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know the final size of each `vectors` for each couple `A,B` so to read all my `vectors` I'll need to do : `DO i=1,Cmax` that why I would like to know this specific `Cmax` (and also to allocate an other array that will received data)

Comment: Why not use `UBOUND` to get the upper bound on the instance of `vectors` for that specific pair of `A` and `B`?  Depending on your compiler, you may be able to allocate automatically upon assignment, or you can use the result of `UBOUND` to get the upper extent that you need to allocate.

Comment: Show the code using SIZE that gives an error.  SIZE can be used to get the number of elements of an array component.

Comment: `UBOUND` works ! thanks a lot